# gltf2.0 export ignores "Inherit Rotation" property changes

Tags: export, bones, gltf

This potentially affects other bone properties, but this is the only one I'm comfortable with messing with. Is this simply not something that's supported by gltf2.0 or is there a setting I'm missing during export?

Edit: Looks like this is an issue with an a [solution](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/880) currently being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glTF has a straightforward node hierarchy, where children always inherit all of their parent's transforms.  It may not be able to exactly match Blender's options for things like "Inherit Rotation" specifically.

That said, there is an "Always Sample Animations" checkbox under the animation section of the glTF exporter.  This is on by default, and is intended to pick up the effects of all sources of animation, including Inherit Rotation.  If you think you've found a bug, check the [issue tracker](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues) for similar issues, or file a new issue there.

Comment: Wow! Good to know this was already thought about in the design. It looks like it's simply not working in my case then. Based on what I can find in the issue tracker, I may need to open a new one. Thanks for the quick reply!